# Import csv into SQLite without single quotes

Tags: sqlite, csv

I have a data in .csv file in format

```
first_name,second_name,nick_name
```

etc.

and the values in .csv are stored with single qutoes 
for example

```
'John','Wick','Johny'
```

I want to import these data into newly created SQL database but i want to get rid of these single quotes.

I am importing this file into table newly created table applicants like this:

```
.mode csv
.import applicants.csv applicants
```

Does anyone have an idea how i can imort these data without quotations?

Comment: Would importing and then getting rid of the quotes or first getting rid of the quotes and then importing be an option? I.e. do you insist on finding a way to import which implicitly gets rid of the quotes?

Comment: @Yunnosch of course it is, i only care about final result :)

Comment: Is in your scope any input imaginable, which needs the quotes for avoiding ambiguity? I.e. do you have something like "Haegar the terrible" or worse "Queen Elisabeth II, ruler of the Commonwealth, head of the church of England". (Sorry if I got the title wrong, my bad; but hopefully you agree that it is still a good example for my question.)

Comment: The current SQLite CLI provides a [quote mode](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#changing_output_formats) which does exactly this, available since [version 3.16](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/changes.html#version_3_16_0).